# my .htaccess not working and taking me to 404, i want to use https also

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have addon domain

```
public_html/example.com
```

in addon domain there is one sudirectory i have my CodeIgniter setup overthere.

```
public_html/example.com/dir1
```

I have added following code in my .htaccess i have also enable SSL on my domain.

```
url like
https://example.com/dir1/
```

My htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Is anything wrong with my .htaccess

below url take me to 404

https://example.com/dir1/controller

Comment: "not working" it too generic, _what_'s not working?

Comment: https://example.com/dir1/controller take me to 404

Comment: And `example.com/dir1/index.php/controller`?

Comment: its work with index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Guys so stupid i am, i dont have added `RewriteBase /livephpchat/`. thanks for your time.